# How to make the pagination to decress the number of links but show all the records

Tags: php, pagination

Here is how the index will show the links for pagination:

```
total record = 40
per_page = 2
```

and now for the link generating:

```
<?php
                if ($pagination->total_pages() > 1) {

                    if ($pagination->has_previous_page()) {
                        echo "<a href='index.php?page=";
                        echo $pagination->previous_page();
                        echo "&refone=" . $refone ."'>&laquo; PREVEOUS</a> ";
                    }

                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagination->total_pages(); $i++) {
                        if ($i == $page) {
                            echo " <span class=\"selected\">{$i}</span> ";
                        } else {
                            echo " <a href='index.php?page=" . $i . "&refone=" . $refone ."'>" . $i . "</a> ";
                        }
                    }

                    if ($pagination->has_next_page()) {
                        echo " <a href='index.php?page=";
                        echo $pagination->next_page();
                        echo "&refone=" . $refone."'>NEXT &raquo;</a> ";
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

metion code will generate the links for pagination but the problem is it is showing many links
for example:
we have 40 record in each page we need to show 2 records so it will generate 20 links( **for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagination->total_pages(); $i++) {**) here is the code which will calculate for the links but I want to echo only 8 links the rest should be hid like

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-Next
prev-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-next
```

but its showing all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer::

here I need to change the code for the **for** statement:

```
 for ($i = $page - $per_page; $i <= $page + $per_page; $i++){
```

this will work for me.